# Error condition longer than 1 function if else [EDIT: rowwise]

Tags: r, function, dplyr, vectorization

****TL;DR:** Is my function not vectorised? How can I vectorise a function calling other functions with many if & else statements? **Many thanks!****

**EDIT: The function works when manually doing one tree at a time by hand in the console, or dplyr-style when using `dplyr::rowwise`**

I'm writing a function containing a lot of if's and 'else's.

The function decides, depending on which arguments are supplied (or missing), on which function to use to calculate the volume of a tree.

I want to use it like this, dplyr-style, over a huge data sheet with many cases.

```
tree_data %>% mutate(volume = tree.volume(dbh.cm = dbh.cm, height.m= height, species.latin=species.latin, latitude= latitude)
```

It is common that crown.base.height.m and double.bark.mm are missing (there are volume functions without these arguments).

```
tree.volume <- function(dbh.cm,height.m,crown.base.height.m,double.bark.mm,species.latin,latitude){
  if(grepl("^Pinus", ignore.case=TRUE, species.latin)){
    pinus_spp_vol(species.latin = species.latin,
                  dbh.cm = dbh.cm,
                  height.m = height.m,
                  latitude = latitude,
                  double.bark.mm = double.bark.mm,
                  crown.base.height.m = crown.base.height.m)
  } else if(grepl("^Picea|^Abies",ignore.case = TRUE, species.latin)){
    picea_spp_vol(dbh.cm = dbh.cm,
                  height.m = height.m,
                  latitude = latitude,
                  crown.base.height.m = crown.base.height.m)
  } else if(grepl("^Larix", ignore.case = TRUE, species.latin)){
    larix_sibirica_vol_carbonnier_1954(dbh.cm = dbh.cm,
                                       height.m = height.m,
                                       double.bark.mm = double.bark.mm,
                                       crown.base.height.m = crown.base.height.m)
  }

}
```

I get the warning messages:

> 1: In if (grepl("^Pinus", ignore.case = TRUE, species.latin)) { :
> the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used

> 2: In if (species.latin == "Pinus contorta") { :   the condition has
> length > 1 and only the first element will be used

> 3: In if (dbh.cm >= 4.5) { :   the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used

> 4: In if (latitude >= 60) { :   the condition has length > 1
> and only the first element will be used

I read this as the function not handling one row in my data.frame at a time... and thus believes all my rows are under the same "category" as the first row?

Attached:
The first function from which the if statements causing the errors are read:

```
pinus_spp_vol <- function(species.latin, dbh.cm, height.m, crown.base.height.m, double.bark.mm, latitude){
  if(!missing(crown.base.height.m)){
    if(!missing(double.bark.mm)){
      if(species.latin!="Pinus contorta"){
        if(dbh.cm >= 4.5){ #Brandel, 1990 function 100-4. for Pines above 4.5 cm dbh.
          if(latitude >= 60){
            (10^-1.12715)*(dbh.cm^2.13211)*((dbh.cm+20)^-0.13543)*(height.m^1.58121)*((height.m-1.3)^-0.73435)*(crown.base.height.m^0.06595)*(double.bark.mm^-0.10998)
          } else {
            (10^-1.20042)*(dbh.cm^2.10263)*((dbh.cm+20)^-0.07366)*(height.m^1.99751)*((height.m-1.3)^-1.11357)*(crown.base.height.m^0.06420)*(double.bark.mm^-0.14963)
          }
        } else { #Andersson,1954 for small trees.
          if(latitude >= 60){
            0.22 + 0.08786 * (dbh.cm^2) + 0.03045 * (dbh.cm^2) * height.m + 0.002809 * dbh.cm * (height.m^2)
          } else {
            0.22 + 0.1066 * (dbh.cm^2) + 0.02085 * (dbh.cm^2) * height.m + 0.008427 * dbh.cm * (height.m^2)
          }
        }
      }
    }
  } else {
    if(species.latin== "Pinus contorta"){ #Eriksson 1973
      0.1121*(dbh.cm^2) + 0.02870*(dbh.cm^2)*height.m - 0.000061*(dbh.cm^2)*(height.m^2) - 0.09176*dbh.cm*height.m + 0.01249*dbh.cm*(height.m^2)
    } else {
      if(dbh.cm >= 4.5){#Brandel 1990, 100-01
        if(latitude >= 60){
          (10^-1.20914)*(dbh.cm^1.94740)*((dbh.cm+20)^-0.05947)*(height.m^1.40958)*((height.m-1.3)^-0.45810)
        } else {
          (10^-1.38903)*(dbh.cm^1.84493)*((dbh.cm+20)^0.06563)*(height.m^2.02122)*((height.m-1.3)^-1.01095)
        }
      } else { #Andersson,1954 for small trees.
        if(latitude >= 60){
          0.22 + 0.08786 * (dbh.cm^2) + 0.03045 * (dbh.cm^2) * height.m + 0.002809 * dbh.cm * (height.m^2)
        } else {
          0.22 + 0.1066 * (dbh.cm^2) + 0.02085 * (dbh.cm^2) * height.m + 0.008427 * dbh.cm * (height.m^2)
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are confusing non-vectorized `if () ... else ...` with vectorized `ifelse`.

`if () ... else ...`  takes a single (!!) condition and performs an action on whether the condition is `TRUE` or `FALSE`. If you instead pass a (logical) vector for the condition then only the first element of the vector is chosen to decide which action to perform. As a notfication R will raise a warning. However, besides of that you will in general get a wrong or non-expected result.

`ifelse` on the other hand is vectorized, i.e. both conditions are checked and actions are taken elementwise. For all `TRUE` elements the `TRUE` action is chosen and for all `FALSE` elements the `FALSE` action chosen.

This can best be seen by a simple example:

```r
power2 <- function(x) x^2
power3 <- function(x) x^3

myfun_warning <- function(cyl) {
  if (cyl == 4) {
    power2(cyl)
  } else {
    power3(cyl)
  }
}

myfun_no_warning <- function(cyl) {
  ifelse(cyl == 4, power2(cyl), power3(cyl))
}

# Warning and incorrect result
myfun_warning(mtcars$cyl)
#> Warning in if (cyl == 4) {: the condition has length > 1 and only the first
#> element will be used
#>  [1] 216 216  64 216 512 216 512  64  64 216 216 512 512 512 512 512 512  64  64
#> [20]  64  64 512 512 512 512  64  64  64 512 216 512  64

# No warning and correct result
myfun_no_warning(mtcars$cyl)
#>  [1] 216 216  16 216 512 216 512  16  16 216 216 512 512 512 512 512 512  16  16
#> [20]  16  16 512 512 512 512  16  16  16 512 216 512  16
```

Comment: So it will work when I use dplyr::rowwise because it does not hand the array to the function as a vector?

Comment: Yep. You got it. (; In case of rowwise you are only passing one element of your vector to your function. That's probably not efficient but in that case your code works fine.